# How to read in app purchase statut with flutter ? (in_app_purchase package)

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I search to upgrade purchase function if the purchase is refund.

Currently if I refund,the plugin doesn't have the information of refund. So user keep pro version. How can I read the state of this refund to upgrade purchase function ?

Here is my code

```
 void deliverProduct(PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {

    Stream purchaseUpdated =
        InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.purchaseUpdatedStream;
    _subscription = purchaseUpdated.listen((purchaseDetailsList) {
      _listenToPurchaseUpdated(purchaseDetailsList);
    }, onDone: () {

      _subscription.cancel();
    }, onError: (error) {
      // handle error here.

    });

    if (purchaseDetails.productID == _kConsumableId) {
      await ConsumableStore.save(purchaseDetails.purchaseID);
      List<String> consumables = await ConsumableStore.load();
      setState(() {
        _purchasePending = false;
        _consumables = consumables;

        save_achat_deblocage();

      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _purchases.add(purchaseDetails);
        _purchasePending = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

Even after refund purchase, purchaseDetails.productID keep all previous purchaseID.

Thank you

Comment: For subscriptions I would recommend that you use Revenuecat purchases_flutter package. This just based on my efforts trying to make them work with the other IAP packages.

Comment: I said subscription but it's not a monthly  purchase. Only one take.

Comment: So it's a consumable or non-consumable product purchase, to be accurate. Not my area of experience but hopefully others can help you.

Comment: GrahamD finnaly I test revenuecat but with lifetime purchase. I have same difficulty when I revok purchase, the user stay in Pro version

Comment: @Nitneuq you need to revoke the purchase through RevenueCat for it to be detected.

Comment: I don't know why I have this error when I try to reload initplatformstate to read state of a refun puchase PurchasesError(code=NetworkError, underlyingErrorMessage=thread interrupted, message='Error performing request.')
W/[Purchases] - INFO(18319): Error fetching offerings - PurchasesError(code=NetworkError, underlyingErrorMessage=thread interrupted, message='Error performing request.')